# How to catch the exit codes coming from preinst file while installing debian package?

Tags: command-line, bash, package-management, dpkg

I am trying to install a debian package on my box , through a shell script , i.e in the shell script I am giving the **dpkg -i** command  . Internally there is a **preinst** file which is being used .
Now in this file one of the condition is failing , let's say when **x=0** I am exiting with **exit 2**

I want that whatever exit code that preinst file is exiting with , I should be able to catch that exit code and in my install.sh file, I will do a print statement based on it

Problem is when I am doing **echo $?** it always gives me 1 , stating that dpkg installation failed , but that specific return code I am not getting .  Is there any way to this , Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that some condition is not met in preinst file of the deb package. I think it would be better to move the checks from preinst to the wrapper script i.e. install.sh file.

eg:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$x" -eq "0" ]; then
   echo Check x = 0 failed
   exit 1;
fi
#Put all other such checks here...

dpkg -i package.deb
```

This is assuming you can modify preinst and installer.sh!

This [blog](https://blogs.it.ox.ac.uk/darrencollins/2020/04/07/what-is-an-install-wrapper/) on install wrapper is a good 10-15 min read!

Key Point from blog:

Install wrappers are usually required for one of the following reasons (not limited to these):

1. Pre / Post-requisites
2. Pre / Post scripting, e.g: delete a file / shortcut, create a registry key
3. Pre-install condition checking, e.g: correct OS, correct computer name (or part of name)
4. Check the version of an installed pre-requisite, e.g: version of MS Office
5. Check if a user is logged on
6. Check if a program is in use by the user, e.g: in the event of an upgrade

Comment: One day, link issues may occur between this site and the blog you referred to in your answer. Could you please highlight the vital steps here if not all?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!